# Http2 Client in Angular 7

Tags: angular7, http2

I want to use http2 for client side in my angular project.
I installed http2 with "npm install http2" command and I used sample client code in [http2-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http2).

However, I'm getting below warning

> WARNING in ./node_modules/http2/lib/protocol/index.js 46:12-19
>
> Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which
>   dependencies cannot be statically extracted

With F12 on the page, Console error;

ERROR ReferenceError: process is not defined

```
at Object../node_modules/http2/lib/protocol/framer.js (framer.js:12)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
at Object../node_modules/http2/lib/protocol/endpoint.js (endpoint.js:3)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
at Object../node_modules/http2/lib/protocol/index.js (index.js:41)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
at Object../node_modules/http2/lib/http.js (http.js:136)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
at Object../node_modules/http2/lib/index.js (index.js:18)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

Thus, I cannot get data from server using http2 client. How can I fix these problem?

Comment: this package showing  "This package has been deprecated" why you want exactly this package ?

Comment: Because I couldn't find anything else about using http2 in angular 7. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: you can find here all deprecated library and the replacement for any one 
https://angular.io/guide/deprecations

Comment: I know this page but I couldn't see any information about http2

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need a library for client side HTTP/2. The browser will automatically use HTTP/2 is the server supports it and use HTTP/1.1 I’d it doesn’t.

That’s one of the great things about the way HTTP/2 was implemented - it’s basically seamless to higher level applications like JavaScript.

Of course you might decide to tweak your app differently if HTTP/2 is being used (e.g. bundle less, or push) but those are mostly (and perhaps best) handled the on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I tried to get the data with HttpClient. 

I'm getting error: 

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://http2.pro/api/v1' from origin 'http://..' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Comment: OK but that has nothing to do with HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2. The request is being made and the browser is blocking it because of CORS - as the error indicates. The http2.pro endpoint needs to explicitly allow cross origin calls by returning a special HTTP header.